# how to handle request method from go. I don't use libraries

Tags: http, go, methods

before that I worked with node js and it was easy to understand how to handle methods

example on node js:

```
    switch (request.method) {

    case 'OPTIONS': return OptionsResponse(response);
    case 'GET': return GetSwitch(request, response);
    case 'POST': return PostSwitch(request, response);
    case 'PUT': return PutSwitch(request, response);
    case 'DELETE': return DeleteSwitch(request, response);
    default: return ErrorMessage( "Sorry, this method not supported", 501, request);

}
```

but in go i can't figure out how to do it

```
package utils

import (

    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/user/go_rest_api/src/view" // page view

    "github.com/user/go_rest_api/src/api" // only api server
);
```

How can I implement the same handler in go?

```
func HandlerRequestFunc() {

http.HandleFunc("/", view.Homepage);

/*get method from api server */
http.HandleFunc("/api", api.InfoFromApi);

/* from db api handler */
http.HandleFunc("/api/login", api.Login);
http.HandleFunc("/api/registration", api.Registration);

/* get your list db */
http.HandleFunc("/api/db/list", api.DataBaseList);

/* server start function */
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil));
```

}

how not to process a method inside a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
type MyHandler struct{}

func (self MyHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

}

http.ListenAndServe(":3000", &MyHandler{})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the node.js code in the question translated to Go.  The Go code is very similar to the node.js code.

```
func myHandler(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    switch request.Method {
    case "OPTIONS":
        OptionsResponse(response, request)
    case "GET":
        GetSwitch(response, request)
    case "POST":
        PostSwitch(response, request)
    case "PUT":
        PutSwitch(response, request)
    case "DELETE":
        DeleteSwitch(response, request)
    default:
        http.Error(response, "Sorry, this method not supported", 501)
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand, but I need to insert this into every function. And I want to do it as the top handler

Comment: @Cthulhu Show the node.js "top handler" feature in the question.  There's probably a simple translation of that code to  Go.

Comment: that's what he is

Comment: let's say I have such a scheme in go

Comment: package main

import "github.com/user/go_rest_api/src/utils" // utils



func main() {

 utils.HandlerRequestFunc();

}

Comment: you can see this function in the post

Comment: i can't pass response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request

without

http.handler('path', function)


it is assigned to the path, how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need wiriting response and request for your code
like this. because is the default package of the language

```
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
switch request.Method {
case "OPTIONS":
    OptionsResponse(response, request)
case "GET":
    GetSwitch(response, request)
case "POST":
    PostSwitch(response, request)
case "PUT":
    PutSwitch(response, request)
case "DELETE":
    DeleteSwitch(response, request)
default:
    http.Error(response, "Sorry, this method not supported", 501)
}
```

}